# For which positive integers $m$ and $n$ do $x^m-x$ and $x^n-x$ being integers imply that $x$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, integers

This is inspired by
[Prove that $x$ is an integer if $x^4-x$ and $x^3-x$ are integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420991/prove-that-x-is-an-integer-if-x4-x-and-x3-x-are-integers)

For which positive integers $m$ and $n$
do $x^m-x$ and $x^n-x$
being integers
imply that
$x$ is an integer.

$x$ is assumed to be real.

I don't really have an idea
of what to do
except for the idea that
this probably holds if
$m$ and $n$
are relatively prime,
in which case there are integers
$a$ and $b$ such that
$am-bn=1$.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5Em-x%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5En-x%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [x^2-x,x^n-x integers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2494726p21020815) and [If a polynomial is integer for a x show that x is integer](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1797329p11919555), which indicate it's true for $m = 2$ and any $n \ge 3$.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or $x \in \mathbb{C} $? If $\gcd(m - 1, n - 1) \ge 3$ then the system $x^m - x = x^n - x = 0$ has complex solutions.

Comment: $x$ is a real number.

Comment: There is some resemblance to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737448/real-number-x-such-that-xn-is-constant-for-all-n-in-s/

Comment: For $(1, n), (n, 1), (n, n)$ this boils down to $x^n-x\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $n = 1$ then take $x$ to be any non-integer, if $n\geq 2$ then $x^n-x-1 = 0$ has a solution in $(1, 2)$. So those three cases don't imply that $x$ is an integer, we can safely assume that $n\neq m$ and $n, m\geq 2$.